# $X\sim N(0,1)$. $E(X^2)=?$ have two different results for me. one is zero other is 1

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value

I have a confusing result:

independent $X\sim N(0,1)$ and I'm looking for $E(X^2)$:

$E(X^2) = E(X \times X)$

$E(X^2) = E(X)\times E(X)$

$E(X^2) = 0 \times 0$

$E(X^2) = 0$

I can also do this:

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$

$E(X^2) = Var(X) + E(X)^2$

$E(X^2) = Var(X) + (0)^2$

$E(X^2) = 1$

Anyone can point out my mistake?

Comment: In general $E(X^2) \not= E(X)*E(X)$ unless $X$ is almost surely constant (if the expectations exist)

Comment: hi @Henry, sorry im not familiar with that statement of surely constant. can you point me in the article/theory?

what im familiar is that the expectation is ()(Y), for both Discrete and Continuous if they are independent. And was proven via the classic computation of the PMF/PDFs of E(XY).

Comment: Welcome to CV, Francis. By definition $E(X)$ ***cannot*** be independent of $E(X)$. I would edit your question (link in the lower left) to add the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: $E(XY)=EX\times EY$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but $X$ and $X$ as in the case here are *definitely* not independent...

Comment: "...expectation is ()(Y), for both Discrete and Continuous if they are independent". True.  But why do you think that $X$ is independent of itself? Wouldn't it be more sensible to assume that $X$ is _not_ independent of Itself on the grounds that if you know the value of $X$, then certainly the value of $X$ is known? (Here I am using the ordinary notion of independence without any mathematical/statistical malarky or high-power concepts such as pdfs and pmfs)

Comment: Taken together, these comments seem to outline a complete answer to the question.

Comment: thank you guys. I overlook the logic of X depending on itself.

Comment: This is similar to [the answer produced by ChatGP I posted a few days ago on my blog](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2022/12/21/anything-and-everything-and-chatgpt/), reproducing the $E[X^2]=E[X]\times E[X]$ mistake...